# Aggregating column according to their names

Tags: r, statistics, sum, aggregate

French student here, so my english's not that great, sorry.

We transformed a data set with species and their locations, to the corresponding origin of theses species and their locations.

The data set has 600~ columns, named U, A, W, L or E (species origin), inside of which a 0 or 1 (presence / absence of a species at location)

and 2 columns with coordonates (corresponding to the data collecting station).

More than 8000 lines, for each station where data was found.

A simplification of the data set would like that :

```
     [Longitude] [Latitude] [A][U][U][L][E][A][U] ... [+600]
[1,]    -5.89      35.71     0  0  1  0  0  1  1
[2,]    -5.89      35.81     0  1  0  0  0  0  1
[3,]    -5.89      36.01     1  0  0  1  1  1  0
[4,]    -5.89      36.1      0  0  0  1  0  1  0
[1,]    -5.89      36.21     1  1  1  0  0  1  1
[2,]    -5.79      35.81     1  1  0  1  0  1  0
[3,]    -5.79      35.91     0  1  0  0  0  0  1
[4,]    -5.79      36.01     1  1  0  1  0  1  0
[+8000]
```

What we want to do is to some sort of conditional sum, where all origin are regrouped into one column each and their content summed , like so :

```
`
   [Longitude] [Latitude]  [A][U][L][W][E]
[1,]    -5.89     35.71    12 6  5  0  13
[2,]    -5.89     35.81    5  1  8  10 20
[3,]    -5.89     36.01    1 28  3  6  2
[4,]    -5.89     36.1     4  25 0  1  11
[1,]    -5.89     36.21    9  1  9  3  5 
[2,]    -5.79     35.81    6  5  12 1  8 
[3,]    -5.79     35.91    5  2  7  15 10
[4,]    -5.79     36.01    10 3  5  12 4 
[+8000]
```

Only the A,U,L,E,W must be summed.
Longitude, Latitude and number of rows must ne kept the same.

We tried aggregate or tapply, without success, but maybe a loop is needed...

Any ideas ?

[a capture of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwB8S.png)

[MacOs answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHemN.png)

[MacOS answer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1DKv.png)

Thanks

MacOS function : espOri => df       espagg => df.agg

```
espagg <- aggregate(. ~ Longitude + Latitude,
                    especeOri,
                    FUN = sum)


aggregate.columns <- function(especeOri, column.names)
{
  for (column.name in column.names) {
    especeOri[[column.name]] <- rowSums(subset(espagg, select = grep(paste(column.name, ".*", sep = ""), colnames(especeOri))))
  }
  
  return(especeOri)
}

aggregate.column.names <- c("A", "U", "L", "E", "W")

espagg <- aggregate.columns(espagg, aggregate.column.names)

espagg <- subset(especeOri, select = c("Longitude", "Latitude", aggregate.column.names))

View(espagg)
```

dput of the data set

```
 dput(especeOri[1:10,1:20])
structure(list(Longitude = c(-5.89, -5.89, -5.89, -5.89, -5.89, 
-5.79, -5.79, -5.79, -5.79, -5.69), Latitude = c(35.71, 35.81, 
36.01, 36.11, 36.21, 35.81, 35.91, 36.01, 36.11, 35.81), L = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L), A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), E.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.6 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L), L.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    U.7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.8 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), U.9 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), U.10 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), A.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), U.11 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

google drive with all the data sets, a few explanations and our script.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fnWnZZDC3gyWTtSoqi_l7Wuhje5qpJmL?usp=sharing

EDIT : added some values for longitude and latitude to illustrate and a screenshot

Comment: If you transpose your matrix using `t(data)`, then your variable names will be rows. You can then `dplyr` `group_by`, and then `summarize`. Note that all variables in the pre-transposed data frame must be numeric to do this. Can you paste a small example of your data using `dput(data)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the job.

```r
df <- data.frame(Longitude  = c(-5.89, -5.89, -5.89, -5.89, -5.89, -5.79, -5.79, -5.79, -5.89, -5.89),
                 Latitude   = c(35.71, 35.81, 36.01, 36.1, 36.21, 35.81, 35.91, 36.01, 35.71, 35.81),
                 A          = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 U          = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                 U          = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                 L          = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 E          = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                 A          = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                 U          = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1))


df.agg <- aggregate(. ~ Longitude + Latitude,
                    df,
                    FUN = sum)

df.agg$A <- rowSums(subset(df.agg, select = grep("A.*", colnames(df.agg))))
df.agg$U <- rowSums(subset(df.agg, select = grep("U.*", colnames(df.agg))))
df.agg$L <- rowSums(subset(df.agg, select = grep("L.*", colnames(df.agg))))
df.agg$E <- rowSums(subset(df.agg, select = grep("E.*", colnames(df.agg))))

df.agg <- subset(df.agg, select = c(Longitude, Latitude, A, U, L, E))
```

## Update

The OP user asked for a solution where he/she does not have to write the code for `rowSums` explicitely, because he/she has to many columns to actually write it out, i.e. it is inconvinient. The following should do the job.

```r
df <- structure(list(Longitude = c(-5.89, -5.89, -5.89, -5.89, -5.89, 
                             -5.79, -5.79, -5.79, -5.79, -5.69), Latitude = c(35.71, 35.81, 
                                                                              36.01, 36.11, 36.21, 35.81, 35.91, 36.01, 36.11, 35.81), L = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                             0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0L, 1L), A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.2 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0L, 0L), E.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.4 = c(0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.6 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0L, 0L, 1L), L.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
               U.7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), U.8 = c(0L, 
                                                                        0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), U.9 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), U.10 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                           1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), A.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                        0L, 0L, 0L), U.11 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              1L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

df.agg <- aggregate(. ~ Longitude + Latitude,
                    df,
                    FUN = sum)

# This function aggregates rows if their column names have the same start.
# Suppose we have a data frame with column names A, A.1, and A.2. Then,
# the rows of these columns are aggregated using sum. So,
# A     1 1 0
# A.1   2 1 0
# A.2   0 0 1
# becomes
# A     3 2 1
aggregate.columns <- function(df.my, column.names)
{
  for (column.name in column.names) {
    df.my[[column.name]] <- df.my[[column.name]] + 
                              rowSums(subset(df.my,
                                             select = grep(paste(column.name, ".[1-9]+", sep = ""), 
                                                           colnames(df.my))))
  }
  
  return(df.my)
}

aggregate.column.names <- c("A", "U", "L", "E")

df.agg <- aggregate.columns(df.agg, aggregate.column.names)

df.agg <- subset(df.agg, select = c("Longitude", "Latitude", aggregate.column.names))

df.agg
```

The key to making this work is this line.

```r
grep(paste(column.name, ".[1-9]+", sep = ""), colnames(df.my))
```

It returns all column names that have start with the current value of variable `column.name` followed by a dot and any sequence of digits, e.g. when the value of `column.name` is `A` then `A.1`, `A.345`, `A.67`, `A.9798`, `A.111111` should all be returned. Please check!

## Update 3

After the user of the OP provided the data, I did come up with the following. This includes a function for renaming. This is necessary since the data frame has columns with identical names. For example, this function transforms a sequence of column names `A, A, A, A` into `A, A.1, A.2, A.3`.

```r
climate  <- read.table("Data_climate.txt", header = T)
poissons <- read.table("Data_fish.txt", header = T)
traitsNA <- read.table("Data_traits.txt", header = T)

especes <- poissons [,-2]
especes2 <- especes [,-2]
especes3 <- especes2 [,-1]

colnames(especes3) <- traitsNA$Origin
especes44<-cbind(climate$Latitude,especes3)
especeOri <- cbind(climate$Longitude,especes44)
origine <- cbind(climate$ID_cellule,especeOri)

colnames(origine)[1] <- "ID_cellule"
colnames(origine)[2] <- "Longitude"
colnames(origine)[3] <- "Latitude"


colnames(especeOri)[1] <- "Longitude"
colnames(especeOri)[2] <- "Latitude"



rename.columns <- function(df)
{
  unique.column.names <- unique(colnames(df))
  
  for (unique.column.name in unique.column.names)
  {
    idxs.columns <- which(colnames(df) == unique.column.name)
    
    df.tmp.with.new.col.names <- subset(df, select = idxs.columns)
    
    colnames(df)[idxs.columns] <- colnames(df.tmp.with.new.col.names)
  }
  
  return(df)
}

especeOri <- rename.columns(especeOri)

espagg <- aggregate(. ~ Longitude + Latitude,
                    especeOri,
                    FUN = sum)


# This function aggregates rows if their column names have the same start.
# Suppose we have a data frame with column names A, A.1, and A.2. Then,
# the rows of these columns are aggregated using sum. So,
# A     1 1 0
# A.1   2 1 0
# A.2   0 0 1
# becomes
# A     3 2 1
aggregate.columns <- function(df.my, column.names)
{
  for (column.name in column.names) {
    df.my[[column.name]] <- df.my[[column.name]] + 
                              rowSums(subset(df.my,
                                             select = grep(paste(column.name, ".[1-9]+",
                                                                 sep = ""), 
                                                           colnames(df.my))))
  }
  
  return(df.my)
}


aggregate.column.names <- c("A", "U", "L", "E", "W")

espagg <- aggregate.columns(espagg, aggregate.column.names)

espagg <- subset(especeOri, select = c("Longitude", "Latitude", aggregate.column.names))
```

HTH!

Comment: It didn't work, we just want to regroup the A,U,L,W,E cols, keeping Longtitude and Latitude the same, as well as the same number of rows.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHemN.png
It gave me this

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's 8000+ row and 600+ columns, I can't do them one by one like that...

Comment: @user14700052 I updated my answer again. Please check it out! I'm curious if this is what you were asking for.

Comment: Well, it looks like what we're looking for, but unfortunately there're only 0s in cols. It seems the sum didn't work, I tried looking for the cause but I can't find it.
result => https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1DKv.png
I edited my post with your function.

Comment: Damn it! I thought I had it. Can you please post a subset of the data? If not, I might not be able to help you anymore because my code outputs what you want on the little example.

Comment: Yes you were really close apparently, I thought it worked when I saw the new df.
I'd really like to post a subset, but I didn't really understand how to ? With dput() apparently, but I don't know how to use it properly

Comment: Simply call ```dput(df)``` and copy and paste the output here (in your original post). If this is too much, you can limit the number of rows you want to include, e.g. to the first 10 rows ```dput(df[10, ]```.

Comment: Thanks, I put it in my post as you suggested, tell me if there's something wrong !

Comment: Unfortunately, no. For example, for this ```df <- data.frame(Zip_Code = c(35780,35780,35780),
                 Zone_type = c("Semi_urban","Rural","Urban"),
                 Freq = c(0,0,2))``` the output of ```dput(df)``` is ```structure(list(Zip_Code = c(35780, 35780, 35780), Zone_type = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L), .Label = c("Rural", "Semi_urban", "Urban"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(0, 0, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))```. Please try again.

Comment: My bad, I rectified.

Comment: @user14700052 I updated my answer. Please have a look. The new code gives the correct answer on your sample data. In addtion, I corrected a but in my code. Specifically, the pattern did not match what we wanted it to.

Comment: Still the same, no numbers in the cols. It seems the problem comes from my data.frame, since I tried it with your code and df separately and it worked. A friend of mine thinks it may be that my values are not considered numerical by R. 
Or, maybe i'm not using your function well : am I suppose to keep df.my or should I replace it with my own df ? I'm really not sure, I tried both. Thanks for your help, as always.

Comment: That is awkward. You can inspect your data frame with str(). Can you upload the whole csv and provide a public link, e.g. via google drive? Maybe I can reproduce your issue then.

Comment: I set up a Google Drive, link at the end of the post, it should be available.

Comment: I posted an update. The problem was that your data frame has multiple columns with the samen name, as you pointed out in the OP. However, the data that you provided had different names. In other words, it was a hughe missunderstanding based on a missmatch of what was textually written in your post and data output you provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked ! Really glad you helped us.

Comment: Great! Please consider giving my answer an UpVote too! That said, please check if the output is really what you were looking for.

Comment: I did but since my reputation is low it doesn't count.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using the data you provided.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

fish <- read.table("Data_fish.txt", header = T)
traits <- read.table("Data_traits.txt", header = T)

fish %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID_cellule, Longitude, Latitude), names_to = "Species", values_to = "Occur") %>% 
  mutate(ID_cellule = factor(ID_cellule, levels = unique(ID_cellule))) %>% # use factor to fix the display order as-is
  left_join(traits %>% select(Species, Origin), by = "Species") %>% 
  group_by(ID_cellule, Longitude, Latitude, Origin) %>% 
  summarise(Occur = sum(Occur)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Origin", values_from = "Occur")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8,154 x 8
# Groups:   ID_cellule, Longitude, Latitude [8,154]
   ID_cellule Longitude Latitude     A     E     L     U     W
   <fct>          <dbl>    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1 ID1            -5.89     35.7     8    10     0   178     0
 2 ID2            -5.89     35.8    11    10     0   234     0
 3 ID3            -5.89     36.0     9    11     0   195     0
 4 ID4            -5.89     36.1    12    10     0   227     0
 5 ID5            -5.89     36.2    13    17     0   268     0
 6 ID6            -5.79     35.8     9     8     0   205     0
 7 ID7            -5.79     35.9     8     9     0   168     0
 8 ID8            -5.79     36.0    11    14     0   262     0
 9 ID9            -5.79     36.1    10    10     0   193     0
10 ID10           -5.69     35.8     9    10     0   230     0
```

Comment: Your's worked too, thanks a lot ! I can't accept the two answers as the solution but I upvoted it !

Comment: I UpVoted that answer too. @user14700052 You can cross-check our answer and see if both produce the same output.

Comment: I upvoted both of you, but since i'm a new user it doesn't count apparently...